# Ubuntu Virtual Machine installation on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

[image]

I'm installing Ubuntu Linux on my Windows 10 host using VirtualBox. I arrived at this page after some steps. Should I go ahead and select the first option? Will it delete files on my Virtual Machine (Ubuntu), or the Host Machine (Windows 10)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. It won't delete your files from host OS. This erasing and subsequent installation happens on the virtual OS space that you would have allocated while creating the virtual hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first clears only the VHD.

!! IF YOU INSTALL IT OUT OF YOU VM, DON'T CHOOSE THIS !!